# show that $U^*AU$ has the form $\pmatrix{\lambda_1 & w \\ 0 & A_1 }$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...\lambda_n$ be eigenvalues. Let $x$ be a eigenvector of $\lambda_1$ such that $x^*x=1$ and $U_1$ be a unitary matrix with the columns $[x_1,u_2,...,u_n]$ show that $U^*AU$ has the form
$$\pmatrix{\lambda_1 & w \\ 0 & A_1  }$$

where $A_1$ carry matrix of order $n-1$ and $w$ line vector $\mathbb C^{n-1}$.\

I'm absolute beginner to block matrix but i now that $Ax_1=\lambda x_1$ and $U^*U= I$.
Can you help me

Comment: We have $U^*AUe_1=U^*Ax_1=\lambda_1U^*x_1=\lambda_1e_1$ where $e_1$ is the first vector of the standard basis.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  Thank you but can i use the same argument to show  $w$ ?

Comment: @DARULE What do you mean by "to show $w$"? The only thing that is being said about the matrix $U^*AU$ is that its first column is $(\lambda_1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann is $\lambda_1$ an eigenvalue of $A_1$?

Comment: @DARULE $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but not necessarily an eigenvalue of $A_1$.